# he top half of the button is not working when button-style position is absolute

Tags: react-native

### My Problem

When I changed the button-style position to absolute
The top half of the button shows the button-click effect, but navigate('Login') function is not working
but the lower half of the button works without any problems.

### Expected Behavior

When button-style position is absolute,
I want the button to function normally wherever I press it.

### Code Example

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Button } from 'react-native-elements';
import { StyleSheet, Text, View } from 'react-native';
```

```
<View style={styles.grade_view}>
  <Text style={styles.grade_text}>aaaa</Text>
  <Text style={styles.grade_num}>-</Text>
  <Button
  onPress={() => {
    navigate('Login');
  }}
  buttonStyle={{
      backgroundColor: '#AAA',
      width: 140,
      height: 40,
      position: 'absolute',
      borderRadius: 20,
      top: -45,
      right: 10
  }}
  type="solid"
  title="login"
  color="#AAA"
  />
</View>
```

```
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  grade_view: {
    padding: 15,
    borderColor: '#999',
    borderBottomWidth: 1
  },
  grade_num: {
    marginTop: 5,
    fontSize: 26,
    fontWeight: 'bold',
  },
  grade_text: {
    fontSize: 16,
    color: '#AAA'
  }
});
```

### Environment

react-native-cli: 2.0.1

react-native: 0.58.4

node: v10.15.0

npm: 6.4.1

Test Device: iPhone X - 12.1 (XCode Virtual Device)

React Native Environment Info:

System:

OS: macOS 10.14.2

CPU: (4) x64 Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-7360U CPU @ 2.30GHz

Memory: 34.14 MB / 8.00 GB

Shell: 3.2.57 - /bin/bash

Binaries:

Node: 10.15.0 - /usr/local/bin/node

npm: 6.4.1 - /usr/local/bin/npm

SDKs:

iOS SDK:

Platforms: iOS 12.1, macOS 10.14, tvOS 12.1, watchOS 5.1

IDEs:

Android Studio: 3.2 AI-181.5540.7.32.5056338

Xcode: 10.1/10B61 - /usr/bin/xcodebuild

npmPackages:

react: ^16.6.3 => 16.6.3

react-native: 0.58.4 => 0.58.4

npmGlobalPackages:

react-native-cli: 2.0.1

Comment: This is a known bug on Android when you are using a button which is positioned outside of its parent component. On iOS it will work. You need to find a workaround.

Comment: I tested it on  iPhone X - 12.1 Simulator.

Comment: Works perfectly on android.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps something is rendered on top of the half of the button? Have you tried inspecting this? If that would be the case I would use the elevation together with position absolute, but by default it will only work on Android. A handy library to check out (if that is the case): https://github.com/alekhurst/react-native-elevated-view